# Octal literals flagged in regular expression back reference

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, jshint

> jshint emitter                                  emitter/emitter.js: line 15, col 61, Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode.
>
> 1 error

I receive the above message while running the linter jshint on my source code.

The offending line in the program is:

```
let pattern = new RegExp("^-(?=[gim]{1,3}$)(?!.*(.).*\1).*$");
```

jshint flags the error at \1 in the regular expression.

Is there any way to be rid of this message from jshint?

You can view the source  [here](https://github.com/Fernal73/LearnNodeJS/blob/master/emitter/emitter.js)

Comment: I don't know what jshint is thinking, but you should use a regex literal and not the RegExp constructor in this case.

Comment: Thanks. What was I thinking?

Answer (score 4):

In node.js you have to antislash the antislash `(one for node, one for the regex)` due to how node.js is dealing with strings.

```
new RegExp('^-(?=[gim]{1,3}$)(?!.*(.).*\\1).*$');
```

---

---

[image]

Comment: Not just in Node; in *any* JavaScript environment.

Comment: It's basic JavaScript string syntax. I have no idea where the "octal literal" error is coming from, but the problem is that in any JavaScript string literal, backslashes ("antislash" is a better word!) have to be escaped.

Comment: I don't get an error from Node when I try the code in the OP. *edit* oh wait, I do in strict mode. I'm going to need more coffee ...

Comment: @Pointy I feel you ahahah third of the day